# undefined reference to `vtable for class' in Qt project with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

With this `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(EventCameraAnalysis
  LANGUAGES CXX C
  VERSION 0.1.0) 

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
# set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
# set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
# set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets Charts REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(libs/qcustomplot)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/EventCameraThread.cpp src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Charts qcustomplot)

target_include_directories(
  EventCameraAnalysis
  PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
         $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include>
         $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY)
```

`EventCameraThread.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>

#include <metavision/sdk/driver/camera.h>

class EventCameraThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    EventCameraThread(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    ~EventCameraThread();

    void run() override;

signals:
    void newFrame(const QImage &frame);
    void error(int socketError, const QString &message);

private:
    QMutex mutex_;
    QWaitCondition cond_;
    bool quit_;

    Metavision::Camera camera_;
};
```

and `EventCameraThread.cpp`:

```
#include <event_camera_analysis/EventCameraThread.h>

EventCameraThread::EventCameraThread(QObject *parent)
: QThread(parent), quit_{false} {}

EventCameraThread::~EventCameraThread() {}


void EventCameraThread::run() {
}
```

I get the following errors when building

```
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/QtGui:61,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupportDepends:4,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupport:3,
                 from /data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/libs/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h:97,
                 from /data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/src/main.cpp:19:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:56:2: warning: #warning qopenglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined [-Wcpp]
   56 | #warning qopenglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:57:2: warning: #warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h [-Wcpp]
   57 | #warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h
      |  ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/qopenglextrafunctions.h:47,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/QtGui:62,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupportDepends:4,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtPrintSupport/QtPrintSupport:3,
                 from /data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/libs/qcustomplot/qcustomplot.h:97,
                 from /data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/src/main.cpp:19:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/qopenglfunctions.h:49:2: warning: #warning qopenglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined [-Wcpp]
   49 | #warning qopenglfunctions.h is not compatible with GLEW, GLEW defines will be undefined
      |  ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/QtGui/qopenglfunctions.h:50:2: warning: #warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h [-Wcpp]
   50 | #warning To use GLEW with Qt, do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h
      |  ^~~~~~~
[100%] Linking CXX executable EventCameraAnalysis
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/EventCameraAnalysis.dir/src/EventCameraThread.cpp.o: in function `EventCameraThread::EventCameraThread(QObject*)':
/data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/src/EventCameraThread.cpp:4: undefined reference to `vtable for EventCameraThread'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/EventCameraAnalysis.dir/src/EventCameraThread.cpp.o: in function `EventCameraThread::~EventCameraThread()':
/data/repos/phd/event_camera_analysis/src/EventCameraThread.cpp:6: undefined reference to `vtable for EventCameraThread'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EventCameraAnalysis.dir/build.make:155: EventCameraAnalysis] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: CMakeFiles/EventCameraAnalysis.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

Any idea how I can get this CMake setup working?

**Solution:**
Using `qt_wrap_cpp` in CMake did the trick.

My `CMakeLists.txt` now looks like the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(EventCameraAnalysis
  LANGUAGES CXX
  VERSION 0.1.0) 

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Widgets Charts REQUIRED)

find_package(MetavisionSDK COMPONENTS core driver ui REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(libs/qcustomplot)

qt_wrap_cpp(SOURCES include/event_camera_analysis/EventCameraThread.h
                    include/event_camera_analysis/QtGuiApplication.h)

qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/EventCameraThread.cpp src/QtGuiApplication.cpp ${SOURCES} src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
  Qt6::Core Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Charts qcustomplot MetavisionSDK::core MetavisionSDK::driver MetavisionSDK::ui)

target_include_directories(
  EventCameraAnalysis
  PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
         $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/include>
         $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
  PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC cxx_std_17)

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: The message seems to tell you to start by looking at line 19 in main.cpp. It is probably not a CMake thing, but about what the source contains. In particular *"do not include <qopengl.h> or <QOpenGLFunctions> after glew.h"*

Answer (score 0):

Error `undefined reference to vtable` occurs when pure virtual function definition is missing in either base class or derived class.

In your example it's already overriding and defining virtual function `run()` which means no virtual function definition missing in your code implementation.

In case of Qt if you don't define macro `Q_OBJECT` to get signal and slot definition and other meta object definition, you may get same error but your code includes that already.

From your code I don't see anything wrong.

Though there is a possibility that your build folder might be having older files generated while writing code.
I would suggest you to delete build folder and regenerate with cmake and try again.

Regarding OpenGL warning, I don't think they are cause of the error. But if you can share full code and what libraries needs to be installed to reproduce this error?, may get more help.

Comment: I have deleted the content of the build folder, run cmake and make several times without any success.

Comment: @AndreasZiegler Have you checked the source folder for generates files, like `moc_*.cpp`?

Comment: @hyde According to the automoc documentation (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-qt.7.html#automoc), moc_*.cpp should be added automatically. Or do you mean I should check if these files are generated at all?

Comment: @AndreasZiegler If you use a separate build directory (as you should), but accidentally build ln source directory too, then the extra files generated to source directory remain there and may get used instead of newer files in correct build directory. In this case these generated files may need to be removed by hand from the source directory (remeber backups and/or making sure version control has the latest code, if you're not 100% sure what to remove).

Comment: @hyde I do use a separate build directory. I posted the output of `VERBOSE=1 make` here (https://pastebin.com/y0eCMxy2). `mocs_compilation.cpp` gets built and also linked with the rest. Therefore, it looks to me as Qt is run the right way by CMake. But linking fails.